# Filter an array of objects / convert array into another

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

could you please help me to convert data in format like :

```
"tanks": [
      {
          "id": "1",
          "name": {
              "id": 1,
              "tor": "000"
          },
          "type": {
              "id": 1,
              "system": "CV-001"
          }
      }
  ]
```

into

```
"tanks":[
      {
          "type": 1,
          "name": 1 
      }
  ]
```

As you can see, type.id in the first array is the same as just type in the second. It is like I have to iterate through the array(as I have not only one Object in it) and left only needed fields in Objects, but I am stuck.
Hope it is a little informative for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var obj = {
  tanks : [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": {
        "id": 1,
        "tor": "000"
      },
      "type": {
        "id": 1,
        "system": "CV-001"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": {
        "id": 2,
        "tor": "200"
      },
      "type": {
        "id": 2,
        "system": "CV-002"
      }
    }
  ] 
};

obj.tanks = obj.tanks.map(function(item) {
  return { 
    name : item.name.id,
    type : item.type.id
  };
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, That's it!